# react redux / react thunks api

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Hello I am trying to consume my api
using react redux and thunks

but without success

my code so far:

my actions:

```
import {FETCHING_PRODUCTS_SUCESS, FETCHING_PRODUCTS_FAIL, FETCHING_PRODUCTS_REQUEST} from '../constants/ActionsFetch';
import api from '../../services/api'

export const fetchingProductsRequest = () => ({type: FETCHING_PRODUCTS_REQUEST});

export const fetchingProductsSucess = (json) => ({
  type: FETCHING_PRODUCTS_SUCESS,
  payload: json
});

export const fetchingProductsFail = (error) => ({
  type: FETCHING_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
  payload: error
})

export const fetchProducts = () => dispatch => {
    return async dispatch => {
      dispatch (fetchingProductsRequest ());
      try {
        let response = await api.get ('/ subcategory');
        console.log (response);
        let json = await response.json ();
        dispatch (fetchingProductsSucess (json));
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch (fetchingProductsFail (error));
      }
    }
}
```

my reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isFetching: false,
    products: [],
    errorMessage: '',
};


export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCHING_PRODUCTS_REQUEST:
        return {... state,
                isFetching: true
                }
      case FETCHING_PRODUCTS_SUCESS:
        return {... state,
                isFetching: true,
                products: action.payload
                }
      case FETCHING_PRODUCTS_FAIL:
        return {... state,
                isFetching: false,
                errorMessage: action.payload
              }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

my store:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore (rootReducer, applyMiddleware (thunk));

export default store;
```

and my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchProducts} from '../../store/actions/ProductsFetch';
class index extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.fetchProducts ();
  }
  
  render () {
    console.log (this.props.Products);
    if (this.props.Products.isFetching) {
      console.log ('a');
    }
    return (
      <div>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    Products: state
  };
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, {fetchProducts}) (index);
```

I gave a .log console to my render:

and received it:

> {productsFetch: {…}} productsFetch: {isFetching: false, products:
>   Array (0), errorMessage: ""} __ proto__: Object

by giving console.log in my action
do not pass that part:

return async dispatch =>

Comment: I prefer to provide a best practice from Microsoft using redux + thunk, here is the [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/frontend-bootcamp), you can find the related code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/frontend-bootcamp/tree/master/bonus-servicecalls)

Comment: I was a little lost because of the type script

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you're returning too many functions from `fetchProducts`.

Correct `fetchProducts` should be

```
export const fetchProducts = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch (fetchingProductsRequest ());
  try {
    let response = await api.get ('/ subcategory');
    console.log (response);
    let json = await response.json ();
    dispatch (fetchingProductsSucess (json));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch (fetchingProductsFail (error));
  }
}
```